# Error: PIN_B0 undeclared in XC16

Tags: pic

I am attempting to write some code for a PIC24FJ64GB002 using X16. I am not a software developer, so very much a "noob" here.

I am trying to make RB0 (pin 4) go low on an event using the code:

```
        if(joyd.x_axis < 127)
        {output_low(PIN_B0);} else{output_high(PIN_B0);} //if LEFT pressed
```

This gives a warning:

implicit declaration of function 'output_low'

and an error:

error: 'PIN_B0' undeclared (first use in this function)

I have been googling all morning to no avail. Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolve these two issues please?

Comment: Normally it would be as simple as `LATBbits.LATB0 = 0;` Are you migrating this code from elsewhere?

Comment: No Roger, the code has not been migrated. I tried your suggestion but it didn't seem to make any difference. Cheers anyway.

Comment: People sometimes `#define` macros such as `output_low`, maybe you're missing a header file? It was also similar syntax to the CCS compiler, rather than XC16.

Comment: Is there a simpler way of making a pin go low?

Comment: This worked:if(joyd.x_axis < 127)
   {PORTBbits.RB0 = 0;} else{PORTBbits.RB0 = 1;} //if LEFT pressed

Comment: Yes, if you're using XC16 then my first comment will write zero to pin RB0. Of course you first have to configure it as an output by clearing the relevant TRIS bit: `TRISBbits.TRISB0 = 0;` Some PICs don't have the LAT registers (I'm surpries a PIC24 doesn't though) in which case, you can use `PORTB` directly. However, if you have LAT, you should use it instead of PORT.

Comment: If you check the XC16 `p24fj64gb002.h` device header file, you will find the LATB data structure defined - `LATBbits.LATB0` is perfectly acceptable syntax for that part. (I'm currently working with that exact part in a development project.)

Answer (score 1):

The implicit declaration warning for `output_low` means that the C compiler can't find a function definition for `output_low`: either you didn't write the code for it, or you didn't `#include` in some external code/macro/library to define what that function actually is.

The error for `PIN_B0` is similar: the C compiler doesn't know what `PIN_B0` is. Meaning, it's not a variable or a `#define` anywhere in your program.

For XC16, the SFRs and ports are defined in device-specific headers, found in the \support folder under the specific device family (PIC24, dsPIC33, and so on) - see \support\PIC24F\h\p24fj64gb002.h for your specific part.

You will need to `#include <xc.h>` to get those definitions showing up nicely in your workspace - after which you may use `TRISBbits.TRISB0` to set the mode (in or out), `PORTBbits.RB0` to read from the line and `LATBbits.LATB0` to write to the line.